# FIDE rating in blitz

Tags: rating, fide

I played in a blitz tournament. It was an official FIDE tournament, so ratings should be calculated. I wasn't rated before that tournament. It was played over 11 rounds with a rematch so you could earn 22 points. I had 11 points, but after the event I am still not rated in blitz. Everyone else in tournament has changed their ratings. Why didn't I get a FIDE rating? What do. I need to do to get FIDE blitz rating?

---

If someone can check, [this](https://ratings.fide.com/calculations.phtml?id_number=21889090&period=2019-11-01&rating=2) is my result from this tournament

Answer (score 6):

> Why didn't I get a FIDE rating?

Probably because you didn't meet the requirements to get a rating.

According to *FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 July 2017* (sorry no link currently because FIDE have munged their site and you have to search withing the site):

> 7. **Official FIDE Rating List**
>
> 7.1 On the first day of each month, the QC shall prepare a list which incorporates the rated play during the rating period into the previous list. This shall be done using the rating system formula.
>
> 7.11 The rating period (for new players, see 7.14) is the period where a certain rating list is valid.
>
> 7.12 The following data will be kept concerning each player whose rating is at least 1000 as of the current list:
>   FIDE title, Federation, Current Rating, ID Number, Number of games rated in the rating period, Date of Birth, Gender and the current value of K for the player.
>
> 7.13 The closing date for tournaments for a list is 3 days before the date of the list; tournaments ending before or on that day may be rated on the list.
>   Official FIDE events may be rated on the list even if they end on the last day before the list date.
>
> 7.14 A rating for a player new to the list shall be published only if it meets the following criteria:
>
> 7.14a If based on results obtained under 6.3, a minimum of 5 games.
>
> 7.14b If based on results obtained under 6.4, a minimum of 5 games played against rated opponents.
>
> 7.14c The condition of a minimum of 5 games need not be met in one tournament. Results from other tournaments played within consecutive rating periods of not more than 26 months are pooled to obtain the initial rating.
>
> 7.14d **The rating is at least 1000**.
>
> 7.14e The rating is calculated using all his results as if they were played in one tournament (it is not published until he has played at least 5 games) by using all the rating data available.

Without more information it is not possible to say exactly why you didn't get a rating. If you can give a link to the tournament and your real name it would be possible to have a look and see why.

**EDIT**: Thank you for giving details of the tournament that you played in.

It was played on 12th October 2019. This will be rated in the list that comes out on 1st November. In the meantime FIDE have recorded that they expect your blitz rating to be 1503. You can see [here](https://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=21889090). They don't know yet for sure because maybe you played in another tournament and they didn't get the tournament report file yet.

> What do I need to do to get FIDE blitz rating?

Basically you need to score at least 0.5 points against at least 5 players who are already FIDE rated at blitz in one or more FIDE rated blitz tournaments over a period of 26 months or less and get a rating of at least 1000.

If you want to calculate your initial rating then FIDE provide an [initial rating calculator](https://ratings.fide.com/calculator_rp.phtml) in a part of their site which has not yet been munged.

If you think you satisfied these requirements and still didn't get a blitz rating you can email the chairman of the [Qualification Commission](https://ratings.fide.com/fide_directory.phtml?content=6), Nick Faulks (armadillo@northrock.bm) or the secretary, Alex Holoczak (alexholowczak@gmail.com).

Comment: Brian, https://old.fide.com/   Also, did you see my new post about the 75-move rule?

Comment: What does "munged the site" mean?

Comment: @PedroA "Mung" is a self referential acronym from the Unix days of the 70's. It stands for "Mung Until No Good". It basically means, you had something which worked perfectly well but you kept changing it until it stopped working.